# Laravel Form Routing With Multiple Variables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Here is my blade Form tag in my view;

```
{{ Form::model($client_agreement, array('route' => array( 'clients/'.$client->id.'/client-agreements.update', $client_agreement->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

Here are my routes;

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');

Route::resource('agreements', 'AgreementController');

Route::resource('clients/{id}/client-agreements', 'ClientAgreementController');
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the form to submit to the 3rd Route. But instead I keep getting the error;

```
Route [clients/5/client-agreements.update] not defined.
```

All my other RESTful routes seem to be working ok but this is the first time I've had to pass more than one variable. ie. the `$client->id` and the `$client_agreement->id` - both of which exist as I can print them out on the screen.

Comment: There's a section about "Handling Nested Resource Controllers" on here (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) - is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [nested resources](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) (you need to scroll down a bit in the docs)

You just use the "dot" syntax to specify a nested resource and Laravel will take care of the rest:

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');

Route::resource('agreements', 'AgreementController');

Route::resource('clients.agreements', 'ClientAgreementController');
```

The URL will be `clients/1/agreements` or `clients/1/agreements/1` depending on the method.

This will also change how the function parameters look inside the `ClientAgreementController`.

```
index($clientId)
create($clientId)
store($clientId)
show($clientId, $agreementId)
edit($clientId, $agreementId)
update($clientId, $agreementId)
destroy($clientId, $agreementId)
```